# Is Sansa and Tyrion's marriage still legitimate?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

As of the end of Season 6 of Game of Thrones, it seems very likely that Daenerys and her fleet/army will, at some point, come into contact with Jon Snow and the North.  It's entirely possible that they'll become allies - they both want the Lannisters removed from power, and they have a mutual friend in Theon Greyjoy.

As Daenerys said, "The best way to make alliances is with marriage."  I know there's been a lot of speculation about a possible marriage between

> Daenerys and Jon.

But what about the fact that Daenerys's Hand of the Queen has already been married to Jon's sister?  And the relationship between Tyrion and Sansa, while not exactly loving, was better than how Tyrion and Shae's time ended, and certainly went better than Sansa and Ramsay's marriage.  So the two of them might be amenable to the idea of marrying for the sake of their respective factions.

But a lot has happened since then - Sansa was married to Ramsay, and Tyrion was convicted of murdering his nephew and fled the kingdom after killing his father.  And the lords of the north might not be so keen to kneel to a Lannister.  If the marriage is no longer seen as legitimate by the populace then it would defeat the purpose of sealing the alliance.

So my question is: **Assuming Sansa and Tyrion want to resume their marriage, is there any law, custom, or precedent in Westeros that could prevent them from doing so?**

Comment: since they never consummated the marriage, there's a real question if it was ever "valid" in the first place...

Comment: As @KutuluMike points out, Sansa's marriage to Tyrion was not consumated, while her subsequent marriage to Ramsay certainly was. It seems unlikely that they could just "resume" their marriage, although with Ramsay dead they could presumably remarry if they wanted to.

Comment: Marriage alliances usually happen because the woman will have "huge tracts of land" that the man is interested in. Considering the North is almost the size of all the other kingdoms put together the match may make sense. It would all help to repair the damage between the houses.

Comment: I question the usefulness of that spoiler. As long as you don't go into why, I don't think it's a spoiler.

Comment: Bordering on being a duplicate of http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/95350/isnt-sansa-already-married

Comment: @KutuluMike A non consummated marriage can only be set aside if at least one party presents the case for divorce in front of a council of faith. As neither Sansa nor Tyrion have done it, I'd argue their marriage is pretty legitimate and marriage to Ramsay would be illegal.

Comment: “they have a mutual friend in Theon Greyjoy” — *friend*? Sansa’s sympathies aside, I would have thought Jon would be duty bound to execute Theon if he met him.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite For what Crime? Rickon being alive proves Theon never killed Bran and Rickon. Theon did swear an oath of fealty to Robb but if Robb considered himself and his bannermen free of oaths sworn to Iron throne after crowning himself as KiTN then Why should Theon be bound to his oath when his Father crowned himself as Iron King? Theon was a Greyjoy, not a Stark. His allegiance is to his House ultimately.

Comment: However, One could say that any lord who meets Jon, would be honor bound to behead the Bastard of Winterfell for deserting Night's Watch as there is no clear indication of termination of service in NW oaths. It does say **It will not end until my death** but it also says **for all the night's to come** which hints that NW vows are for eternity

Comment: @Aegon: Regarding Theon’s loyalty, eh I guess. But he still murdered those two farm boys in an attempt to make the north think that Bran and Rickon were dead. Death sentence for that, surely? And just to nitpick: 1. Rickon being alive proves Theon never killed Rickon. It proves nothing about Bran unless Rickon talks about it. 2. I still maintain that Jon *hasn’t deserted* the Night’s Watch — he’s serving it by uniting the north against the White Walkers. It’s all he ever talks about, the big dullard.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Fair enough I think Theon never told Sansa about the murders and Rickon never got a chance to talk. But it should make Jon/Sansa think that if Rickon is alive, Could bran be alive as well? I don't believe Westeros is kind of society which punishes nobles for killing peasants. Most probably no one would even bother to bring it up.

Comment: @Aegon: I think Theon did explain the farm boy murder to Sansa in the TV show. (I’ve not read the books but I understand that Theon and Sansa don’t/haven’t yet met there.) But sure, Rickon’s appearance definitely throws a lot of doubt on the idea that Theon murdered both of them. I know what you mean about the farm boy thing perhaps not being treated that seriously.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Source:** [Wiki of course, where else would we get our knowledge?](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Marriage)

#### The Books

The Wikia page states that a marriage can be annulled if it is not consummated, this can only happen by request and must be approved by The High Septon **or** A Council of Faith.

That means that a marriage is not automatically invalid if not consummated.

#### The TV series

In the TV series it is stated many times that the marriage between Sansa and Tyrion is not legit because they did not consummate it. Most of the times this is said by the people who want to marry Sansa to someone else or benefit from their lack of marriage.

**If** the TV series would follow the rules of marriage of the books, then Sansa's marriage to Ramsey would not be legitimate but her marriage to Tyrion could be.

The information of how an annulment would work could be kept as a plot twist for when the 2 characters meet again.

**Or** the TV series has already given us all the information about marriages and thus not consummating the wedding automatically annuls it, if we are to believe what has been said by (for example) Littlefinger.

In that case, Sansa is now a widow.

#### Extra

The wikia also states that women, who are forced to marry while being a hostage (not to be confused with simply being forced by their parents) can also ask for an annulment.

So Sansa could still ask for an annulment because she was forced to marry Tyrion.

Comment: Who can she ask for an annulment now?

Comment: @HannoverFist the Gods

Comment: @HannoverFist There will be most likely a council of faith assembled at Starry Sept in Old Town now seeing what happened to existing council and headquarters at Sept of Baelor in KL. The council will then crown a new High Septon who will be in Old Town. Old Town is ruled by Hightowers who are bannermen of Tyrells. Tyrells are with Daenerys. Aegon the conqueror was crowned in Starry Sept by the High Septon. Maybe Daenerys will be crowned there as well. hmmm